# Django ImportError: No module named politifact_omniture-1.0

Tags: django

I copied a Django directory named 'politifact' to 'politifact_omniture-1.0' to test new analytics code. I modified settings.py to point to my templates, and then attempted to run the site using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

The server fails to start with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute_manager
    setup_environ(settings_mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in setup_environ
    project_module = import_module(project_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.4-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named politifact_omniture-1.0
```

Is there a line in settings.py that I need to modify to notify Django that the working directory has changed from 'politifact' to 'politifact_omniture-1.0'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"-" and "." are invalid in python module names, try some other name like `politifact_omniture1`